# Inconsistent string/wchar content depending on code's location?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I'm having 3 different kind of results, depending on the free functions I'm using:

```
struct __declspec(dllexport) TimerPair final
{
    long long Time{};
    string Descr;
};

template<typename... T>
wchar_t* Message(T &&... args)
{
    wchar_t message[100];
    swprintf(message, 100, forward<T>(args)...);
    return message;
}

template<typename... T>
void LogMessage(T &&... args)
{
    Logger::WriteMessage(Message(forward<T>(args)...));
}

const wchar_t* ToWchar(string arg)
{
    std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(arg.begin(), arg.end());
    return widestr.c_str();
}
```

and the code in unit tests: (the `o` is a `TimerPair` structure)

```
// v1
LogMessage(L"%s : %.4fms\n", ToWchar(o.Descr), (float)o.Time / 1000000);

// v2
std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(o.Descr.begin(), o.Descr.end());
Logger::WriteMessage(Message(L"%s : %.4fms\n", widestr.c_str(), (float)o.Time / 1000000));

// v3
std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(o.Descr.begin(), o.Descr.end());
wchar_t message[100];
swprintf(message, 100, L"%s : %.4fms\n", widestr.c_str(), (float)o.Time / 1000000);
Logger::WriteMessage(message);
```

The `Logger::WriteMessage` comes from MSFT unit test framework (`using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;`)

In the first two cases, I get results like the following:

[image]

instead of the expected (case 3):

[image]

It looks like there is a pointer problem, but the code looks correct, especially with the value argument (`long long`). What I am missing ?

**Update**. Using `static` for local variables as **Omnifarious** proposed, I got inconsistent result in both v1 and v3 (when used one after the other):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little tricky to untangle all of this, but, there is definitely one problem here. This code:

```
const wchar_t* ToWchar(string arg)
{
    std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(arg.begin(), arg.end());
    return widestr.c_str();
}
```

returns a pointer to dead memory. The memory it returns a pointer to is freed when the function exits and `widestr` goes out of scope. If you changed it to this:

```
const wchar_t* ToWchar(string arg)
{
    static ::std::wstring widestr;

    widestr = std::wstring(arg.begin(), arg.end());
    return widestr.c_str();
}
```

it might start working. But then the function would no longer be re-entrant, and most definitely would no longer be thread safe.

The exact same situation goes for this function:

```
template<typename... T>
wchar_t* Message(T &&... args)
{
    wchar_t message[100];
    swprintf(message, 100, forward<T>(args)...);
    return message;
}
```

`message` goes out of scope and you're returning a pointer to dead stack space. Again, if you changed the function to this:

```
template<typename... T>
wchar_t* Message(T &&... args)
{
    static wchar_t message[100];
    swprintf(message, 100, forward<T>(args)...);
    return message;
}
```

it would probably start working, but again no longer be re-entrant or thread safe.

I would rethink the way you handle this.  This takes advantage of C++'s guaruntees about the lifetime of temporaries to handle the problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

extern void fake_logger_writemessage(wchar_t const *);

template <class T>
class WCharWrapper {
 public:
    WCharWrapper() = delete;  // Make it unconstructable
};

template <>
class WCharWrapper<wchar_t const *> {
 public:
    WCharWrapper() = delete;
    explicit WCharWrapper(wchar_t const *s) : s_(s) {}

    operator wchar_t const *() const { return s_; }

 private:
    wchar_t const * const s_;
};

template <>
class WCharWrapper<::std::wstring const &> {
 public:
    WCharWrapper() = delete;
    explicit WCharWrapper(::std::wstring const &s) : s_(s) {}

    operator wchar_t const *() const { return s_.c_str(); }

 private:
    ::std::wstring const &s_;
};

template <>
class WCharWrapper<char const *> {
 public:
    WCharWrapper() = delete;
    explicit WCharWrapper(char const *s) : s_(s, s + ::std::strlen(s)) {}

    operator wchar_t const *() const { return s_.c_str(); }

 private:
    ::std::wstring const s_;
};

template <>
class WCharWrapper<::std::string const &> {
 public:
    WCharWrapper() = delete;
    explicit WCharWrapper(::std::string const &s) : s_(s.begin(), s.end()) {}

    operator wchar_t const *() const { return s_.c_str(); }

 private:
    ::std::wstring const s_;
};

template <typename T>
T widen_strings(T &&arg)
{
    return ::std::forward(arg);
}

WCharWrapper<char const *> widen_strings(char const *arg)
{
    return WCharWrapper<char const *>(arg);
}

WCharWrapper<::std::string const &> widen_strings(::std::string const &arg)
{
    return WCharWrapper<::std::string const &>(arg);
}

// Capture non-const as well, to make sure they aren't passed through unchanged.
WCharWrapper<::std::string const &> widen_strings(::std::string &arg)
{
    return WCharWrapper<::std::string const &>(arg);
}

template <typename T>
T &&widen_strings(T && arg)
{
    return arg;
}

template<typename... T>
wchar_t const *Message(wchar_t *out, T &&... args)
{
    swprintf(out, widen_strings(::std::forward<T>(args))...);
    return out;
}

template<typename... T>
void LogMessage(T &&... args)
{
    wchar_t msgbuf[100];
    fake_logger_writemessage(Message(msgbuf, ::std::forward<T>(args)...));
}
```

[This version I put on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T8sCCM) should work perfectly. Look towards the very end for an example of how it's used.

Comment: Indeed this solves something but introduces another problem you did not mention: the 3 versions are in a `for` loop. If I keep say v1 with the "static trick" and v3, then the result of v1 is inconsistent (the string part is not updated) and v3 is **changed** (looks random). See update.

Comment: @Soleil - Yes, I'm working on a real solution now. The `static` thing was a bad hack.

Comment: I think using smart pointers would be helpful. Or a kind of "partial garbage collector".

Comment: can you not just change the function to return the wstring rather than pointers?

Comment: @Soleil - There, an off the cuff suggestion as to how you might handle this. Basically you apply a generic transform to every argument that transforms any ordinary character strings into temporaries holding wide character strings and leaves other arguments alone.

Comment: @PhilM Anything better in the free function is welcome. Including using classes. But I believe we can do something purely functionnal. I'm working here in unit tests, but later I might use this in an interop c# c++ context, and we need to talk with pointers in this context.

Comment: @Soleil - My thing isn't exactly right. But I think it's along the right path, and I'm out of time. :-)

Comment: @Soleil - One big, glaring flaw is that `swprintf` is a C function, and so has a varargs signature, not a C++ vararg template signature. So it will take the `WCharWrapper` classes and do who knows what to them. So there needs to be another transform that automatically calls the conversion operators for the `WCharWrapper` classes. It can't be done inside the `widen_strings` function because the temporaries have to live until the end of the `swprintf` call, so that have to be created and destroyed inside of the `Message` function.

Comment: @Omnifarious Could you give an example of how to use the wrapper ? It's not clear to me how it works and how it allows to keep a "pointer" from being freed. Compared to shared pointers, I see the advantage that the wrapper stays on the stack. This is not critical for logging, but for other things this can be very handful.

Comment: @Soleil - It's all on Godbolt now, I added a link to the end of the answer. https://godbolt.org/z/T8sCCM - It may be possible to have fewer specializations of the SWArg` class if you're clever. But currently all the specializations are needed to capture all the different cases that can reasonably arise with use.